# Delete Row With jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

The **extract** of code below successfully creates a table showing records pertinent to the current user.

```
/* display row for each location */ 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
$theID = $row['locationid']; 
echo " <td style='text-align: Center'>{$row['locationname']}</td>\n"; 
echo " <td style='text-align: Left'>{$row['returnedaddress']}</td>\n"; 
echo " <td style='text-align: Center'>{$row['totalfinds']}</td>\n"; 
echo " <form name= 'locationsconsole' id= 'locationsconsole' action= locationsaction.php  method= 'post'><input type='hidden' name='lid' value=$theID/>                                                 <td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Details'/></td><td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Images'/></td><td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Add Finds'/></td><td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'View Finds'/></td><td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Delete'/></td></form>\n"; 
    </tbody> 
    </table> 
    <div align="center"><p id="deletelocationresponse"></p></div>
```

At the end of this section of code, you'll see that there is a `Delete` button. Upon clicking this, a record is deleted from the table and the deletion functionality works correctly.

In addition to the delete button you'll notice that there is a div called `deletelocationresponse`. This runs a jquery script to provide onscreen messages to the user telling them whether the deletion has been successful or not. The code for this is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#locationsconsole').submit(function(){

        //check the form is not currently submitting
        if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){

            //setup variables
            var form = $(this),
                formData = form.serialize(),
                formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
                responseMsg = $('#deletelocationresponse');

            //add status data to form
            form.data('formstatus','submitting');

            //show response message - waiting
            responseMsg.hide()
                       .addClass('response-waiting')
                       .text('Please Wait...')
                       .fadeIn(200);

            //send data to server for validation
            $.ajax({
                url: formUrl,
                type: formMethod,
                data: formData,
                success:function(data){

                    //setup variables
                    var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                        klass = '';

                    //response conditional
                    switch(responseData.status){
                        case 'error':
                            klass = 'response-error';
                        break;
                        case 'success':
                            klass = 'response-success';
                        break;  
                    }

                    //show reponse message
                    responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                               .addClass(klass)
                               .text(responseData.message)
                               .fadeIn(200,function(){
                                   //set timeout to hide response message
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                       responseMsg.fadeOut(300,function(){
                                           $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                           form.data('formstatus','idle');
                                       });
                                   },2000)
                                    setTimeout(function() { 
                                    $('body').fadeOut(400, function(){
                                    location.reload();
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                    $('body').fadeIn(400);
                                     }, 500);
                                     window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
                                 });
                            }, 2000);                           
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        //prevent form from submitting
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#deletelocationresponse {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:4px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font:Calibri;
    font-size:16px;
}

.response-waiting {
    background:url("images/loading.gif") no-repeat;
}

.response-success {
    background:url("images/tick.png") no-repeat;
}

.response-error {
    background:url("images/cross.png") no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

The problem I'm having is that when the `Delete` button is clicked the onscreen message is stuck on the `Please wait` message.

Now I know this script works, because I use it on my other pages, obviously with the relevant fields changed. So I've narrowed it down to a problem in it picking up my form name, which is this line in the jQuery code: `$('#locationsconsole').submit(function(){`.

On my other pages my form is created via HTML whereas this script uses PHP.

I've tried researching this, but I'm not particularly well versed in JavaScript, so I'm not too sure what I should be looking for. Could someone possibly tell me please is there a way to call the form in a different way?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: try debugging the ajax request, use firebug or something, and see if it completes and what it returns. also does the jquery code you show placed after the form element?

Comment: If you're actually generating that html in a loop, you need to either not use ID attributes or make sure they're distinct for each row.  If you have multiple `#locationsconsole` elements, there will be problems trying to select them.

Comment: Just from a UX side of view: do you really have to inform the user about the removal? He should see that right away on the page...

Comment: Hi @GeoPhoenix, thank you for your reply. I've just run this through the JavaScript Console and on the `Network` tab it shows the `loading gif` as pending, and then on the `Console` tab it shows this: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON'` pointing to line 52 in my code which is this:  `form.data('formstatus','submitting');`. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Simon, thank you for this. I do understand what you're saying. As I said earlier I'm really very new to Javascript and web design, and there are possibly better ways to do this, but I was just keen to inform the user. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to do basic debugging.  FireBug, or other client side debugging tools can give you a lot of power.  You can also start putting in alerts.  For example, you can put a code like `alert('got here!');` inline in the javascript to see which line specifically is throwing the error.  If you are using FireBug, you can replace this with `console.log('got here');`

console.log will also allow you to dump nested variables, if you find the problem is in your response.

Secondly, save the rendered page as HTML, and then start to troubleshoot that.  This eliminates the PHP side of the debugging, since you have either a HTML error or an error in the JSON response from the AJAX request.

Client side debugging tools like Firebug will also let you see the AJAX request and the raw response.

Comment: Hi @Brian Hoover, thank you for replying to my post. Please see my comment to GeoPhoenix, following the debugging I've done. Kind regards

Comment: what happens if you put console.log(data) before the parseJSON line?  I don't think that command is necessary, because the AJAX call automatically parses data into a usable JavaScript object.

Comment: Hi @Brian Hoover, thank you for your reply and continued help with this. When I add the line you suggest, so my code looks like this:
`console.log(data),
var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),` the deletion script runs and takes the user to a blank white screen. There are however no errors returned in the `Console`. Kind regards

Comment: it should be console.log(data);  not a comma.  Javascript ends lines (mostly) with semi-colons.

Comment: My apologies. I've changed the line of code. So when I click `Delete` the error I receive is `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON' ` highlighting line 52 as the problem, which is this line in my code: `form.data('formstatus','submitting');` and the `Please wait` message is stuck on the screen as per my original post. kind regards and thanks.

Comment: It should just work by changing responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data) to responseData = data

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I've made the changes. Unfortunately, although the `Please wait` message clears from screen the record is not deleted and I receive the following error in the Console:`Uncaught TypeError: Object Please Wait... has no method 'fadeIn' locationsconsole.php:70
$.ajax.success locationsconsole.php:70
o.extend.speed.E.complete jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19
o.fx.step jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19
F jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19
(anonymous function) jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19` and it locates the problem as being here in my code: `var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),`

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Brian Hoover. I'm very conscious that I've taken up a great deal of your time with, and this is and the problems I have are largely down to my inexperience with JavaScript. I've being looking at my script and I think that I may be able to do something a little different which I think will work. So I'm just writing to say please don't spend anymore time on this. But I just wanted to drop you a line to say thank you for all your time, trouble and effort. Many thanks and kind regards.